# React-Native can't compile for release on Android test-driver

Tags: android, react-native, glog

I don't understand but since a few days, I can't compile anymore my app on Android.

I checked lots of post about it :

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14464

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14417

And they all say :

```
unlink node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver
```

But I don't have any test-driver in my folder so I downloader the glog-0.3.4 from the official website. They have a `test-driver` that is linked to `/usr/share/automake-1.14/test-driver` which seems not to be on my mac neither.

I can't compile anymore and I am stuck with this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
> Could not list contents of '/Users/xxx/Documents/ReactJS/xxx/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

## react-native info

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS 10.14.4
  Node: 8.11.2
  Yarn: 1.9.4
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
  Android Studio: 3.3 AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved actually was :

`unlink third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver`

For some reasons It wasn't in the same folder but got it to work after this.